# how implement onkeydown event for custom buttons in android

Tags: android, button, user-interface, onclick

I have a button defined in my layout, I implement onclick buttons without problems, but now I need to know when my button is doww and up, like onkeydown event for fisical buttons. There is  something like that for customs buttons??. Because onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) have a int keycode but muy custom button haven't. 
I hope someone can take away that query. 
thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is. try this code.

```
    yourButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

               switch ( event.getAction() ) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: break;
                }
                return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can try something like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button button ;
    private Boolean buttonState = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonState = !buttonState;
                if(buttonState){
                    button.setText("Down");
                } else {
                    button.setText("Up");
                }               
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I dont think thats the correct answer He need touch events up and down.You are talking about toggle .

Comment: thank "Yuriy Bugryn", "spanjeta" was right. But your code was helpful because I learned thing more

Comment: ohh, really  I Thought, that he want toggle )))